# What are all the linear transformations that can be done on a 2D cartesian plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am interested in teaching about linear algebra on YouTube, and I have a solid grasp of the basics. However, I am looking for an exhaustive list of all the possible linear transformations of R^2 onto R^2 and unfortunately I couldn't find such a list online.

Comment: I'm assuming you want a more in-depth answer than "all $2 \times 2 matrices$"? That would be completely sufficient though.

Comment: @StephenDonovan That is certainly part of a good answer. It would be nice to have a more categorical, descriptive answer too (rotation, shear, etc.). I suspect I could answer it myself, but I am looking for confirmation from a more authoritative source before I spread information via youtube.

Comment: In that case, I think if you look at the way the basis vectors would be transformed, you could say every linear transformation is the combination of some kind of scaling, shearing, and rotation, because the scaling accounts for the magnitudes of the transformed basis vectors, the shearing accounts for the angle between the basis vectors, and the rotation accounts for the angle between one basis vector and the x-axis. That said, I can't speak to whether this is useful.